# Unexpected row in output file

Tags: header, google-cloud-dataprep

### Google Cloud Dataprep

Hi all,

I am newbie in Google Cloud Platform. I just learn about BigQuery & Dataprep. I have an input csv file (refer input file).

[Input file with headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl2Q7.png)

After wrangling (rename columns) and run job in dataprep, below is preview of output file in BigQuery (refer output file). Not sure why output file has an unexpected "row 1" which shows column names. Column names are either before/after rename.

I examine the output in excel format, it is confirmed "row 1" exists. What could be the issue?

[Output file with headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24BjW.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeated Header when exporting Dataprep recipe as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305077/repeated-header-when-exporting-dataprep-recipe-as-csv)