# Repeated Header when exporting Dataprep recipe as CSV

Tags: csv, header, google-cloud-dataprep

I am using Dataprep within Google Cloud Console. I am trying to export my recipe as a CSV. Export settings are the following:

[image]

[image]

The issue I am facing is that the final result is showing a replicate header, like the following, without any clear reason since the header should be present just once:

[image]

Any idea why this is happening? Any help would be much appreciated :-)
Marco

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a bug. Trifacta is already on it:

Slack conversation:

[image]

Comment: This is fixed and I have tested the same